# Calculating cumulative values for all nodes in a chain in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consisting of an edge lists (FromID/ToID) with various attributes.

```
FromID  ToID    from_median degree  since_0001  total_saved
0002    0001    10  1   30  
0003    0001    20  1   40  
0004    0002    10  2   70  
0004    0003    10  2   70  
0005    0003    33  2   112 
0006    0004    26  3   129 
0007    0004    14  3   148 
0008    0005    22  3   150 
0009    0005    14  3   157 
0010    0007    15  4   178 
0011    0007    28  4   184 
0011    0008    28  4   184 
0012    0008    12  4   188 
0013    0011    30  5   220 
0014    0012    12  5   207
```

df$degree is the distance (in degrees) of df$FromID from the initial df$ToID (0001).

df$total_saved should be df$from_median + the df$from_median value for each ID in its chain: e.g. FromID 0014 should equal 99: 0001 -> 0003 -> 0005 -> 0008 -> 0012 -> 0014 == 20 + 33 + 22 + 12 + 12

I simply populated df$total_saved with

```
df$total_saved <- df$from_median
```

and then tried various combinations of for loops, ifelse() and vectorization approaches (using %in% or match() to match FromIDs and TOIDs) without much luck, only getting correct df$total_saved values up to 2 degrees.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: What happens in the cases where the FromId is duplicated? e.g for 0013 you go to 0011 and then 0007 or 0008?

Comment: Fine to leave them as duplicates, no need to deduplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not totally clear but I try to find a solution. I assumed that you want to have find the total length of all paths below the edge FromID TOid. 
First we make a matrix whether you can come from a point to another point. Next we find the total degree.
Here the code:

```
require("data.table")
require("igraph")
require("matrixStats")

test <- data.table(FromID = as.character(c(2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14)), 
                   ToID = as.character(c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7,8,8,11,12)),
                   degree = c(10,20,10,10,33,26,14,22,14,15,28,28,12,30,12))

igraph <- make_graph(t(test[, .(FromID, ToID)]))
E(igraph)$weight <- test$degree
distances <- distances(igraph, mode = "out")
distances[!is.infinite(distances)] <- 1
distances[is.infinite(distances)] <- 0

# Find the longest chain from each node
chain_dist <- rowMaxs(distances[test$FromID,])
names(chain_dist) <- test$FromID
# Function to find the total length

FindTotalLength <- function(x){
  dist_to <- distances[test$ToID[x],, drop =F]
  names <- c(test$FromID[x], colnames(dist_to)[dist_to == 1])
  return(sum(test[FromID %in% names & ToID %in% names, degree]))
}

# Now we got allt he distances now we have to make sure that the first edge will be to ToID
test[,total_saved := sapply(1 : length(FromID), function(x) FindTotalLength(x))]
> test
    FromID ToID degree total_saved
 1:      2    1     10          10
 2:      3    1     20          20
 3:      4    2     10          20
 4:      4    3     10          30
 5:      5    3     33          53
 6:      6    4     26          76
 7:      7    4     14          64
 8:      8    5     22          75
 9:      9    5     14          67
10:     10    7     15          79
11:     11    7     28          92
12:     11    8     28         103
13:     12    8     12          87
14:     13   11     30         205
15:     14   12     12          99
```

Comment: Thanks! Found it difficult to verbalise the problem but you've got the right sense. Should have thought of an igraph solution. This works perfectly on the dummy data table above; the only is issue is that the actual data table I have has over 1000 rows, and so running the !is.infinite command freezes my relatively slow computer! Wonder if there is an alternative approach